# Taking values from one array and to obtain a different value from a separate array. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm not entirely sure how to word what I am asking here but I have an assignment where two arrays are present.  One array contains strings which are the makes of cars.  The second array contains the price of that car.  The program is to run a for loop through the first array, identify the values that contain that specific make, and then add the prices up in the second array.

This is what I have:

```
<html>
<script>

make = new Array();

make[0]='honda';
make[1]='toyota';
make[2]='pontiac';
make[3]='honda';

price = new Array();

price[0]=35000;
price[1]=35000;
price[2]=40000;
price[3]=45000;


function totalByColor(parameter1){
total=0;
for(i=0;i<make.length;i++){
    if(make[i]=='honda'){
        for(b=0;b<price.length;b++){
            make[i]=price[b]; //This is where I need help!
            total = total + price[b];
        };
    } else {
    };
    return total;
};
return total;
};
</script>
<input type='button' value='test' onclick="alert('Return = '+totalByColor('honda'))">
</html>
```

So I need to set the program up to identify the value in make[0] is relevant to price[0] and make[3] is relevant to price[3], so price[0] and price[3] can be added together in the second for loop, any one have any idea?  Thanks in advance for any help or guidance on this issue

Comment: Use javascript Objects for whatever you doing here. Array's not meant for this.

Comment: In the real world @SrinivasReddyThatiparthy, but OP did say it was given as an assignment.

Comment: @SrinivasReddyThatiparthy that was half my battle in finding information for this problem

Answer (score 0):

If the indices are the same, you don't need another for loop; just use your var `i`:

```
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0, len = make.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (make[i] === 'honda') {
       total += price[i];
    }
}
return total;
```

`total` should be a local variable, and is defined as 0 first, then you can use `+=` to redefine `total` as `total + price[i]`.  It's shorthand for `total = total + price[i]`.  I also included `var` before the `i` in the for loop, because it should be local, and not global; and, you don't need so many semi-colons: after brackets for example `}` (so long as it's not an object you are defining). One more thing is that you have a return statement in your for loop, which means it will only loop over one value before ending the function.  The return statement should be after the for loop.

Comment: that was exactly what I was looking for and sincerely appreciate the help you offered!